# Serving pbf tiles with nginx

Tags: pbf, nginx

I have a folder structure `/foo/bar/baz/static/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf` containing many tiles according to a z/x/y file structure.

With `/foo/bar/baz/` containing an `index.html` and a `style.json`.

I have this [nginx](https://nginx.org/) config to serve the content of the `/foo/bar/baz` folder:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my.server.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /foo/bar/baz;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

I thought it would have done the job of retrieving files nested in subfolders according to the /{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf scheme, but when I browse to http://my.server.org the browser displays the `index.html` fine but the *.pbf files are simply not served (I cannot see them in the network manager, and there's no error actually.)

I'm not used to nginx, how could I load the tiles in the browser using this simple URL pattern: [http://my.server.org/static/tiles/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf](http://my.server.org/static/tiles/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.pbf)?

Comment: I think you need to reload Nginx "Enable the configuration, remove the default Nginx configuration and reload Nginx" https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/07/self-hosted-tile-server.html

Comment: Removing the default coffig didn't change anything. And I always run `nginx -t` and `nginx -s reload` after each change I make to be sure everything is OK with my config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This temporarily fixed the problem:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my.server.org;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /foo/bar/baz;
    index index.html;

    location ~* \.pbf$ {
        include proxy_params;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

But you don't want to have other *.pbf files in your path than your actual tiles.

The encoding (here `gzip`) may also vary depending on your situation.